# How do we understand the left and right module structure of Endomorphism ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, noncommutative-algebra

I am reading some materials about noncommuative algebra which made me very confused.
Let $f: A\to B$ be a injective ring homomorphism between two rings, $A$, $B$ are not necessarily commutative. Then the author writes that:

> Let $r:B\to E=\mathrm{End}_{A}(B)$ denote the canonical inclusion $b\to r_{b}$.

I do not understand the sentence. Since we have map $i$, we could realize $B$ as a two side module of $A$. What is the meaning of $\mathrm{End}_{A}(B)$ here? It means left $A$-module homomorphism or right $A$-module homomorphism or two side $A$ homomorphism?. Also what is $r_{b}$? Does it means $r_{b}(b’)=bb’$ or $r_{b}(b’)=b’b$? I am very confused. Can help me? Thanks a lot. By the way, could you recommend some references with details about this? The book which I am reading does not give any details.

Answer (score 4):

Typically, if not specified, "module" is taken to mean "left module".  Indeed, sometimes people don't even work with right modules at all and instead think of a right module over a ring $A$ as a left module over the ring $A^{op}$ (which is $A$ with the order of its multiplication reversed).  This gives a unified way of treating both left and right modules together so that you don't need to worry about confusing them notationally.

So, in your quote, $B$ is presumably being considered as a left $A$-module, so $\operatorname{End}_A(B)$ refers to the left $A$-module homomorphisms $B\to B$.  This is confirmed by the choice of notation $r_b$: here $r$ stands for "right multiplication", so $r_b$ is the map that takes an element and multiplies it on the right by $b$.  That is, $r_b(b')=b'b$.  It is common to use $r$ or $\rho$ to denote right multiplication in this way while left multiplication would instead be denoted $l$ or $\lambda$.  Right multiplication commutes with left multiplication (this is just what associativity says: first multiplying by something on the right and then multiplying by something else on the left is the same as doing it in the opposite order), so right multiplication gives a homomorphism of left modules.  Explicitly, $r_b$ is a left $A$-module homomorphism since if $a\in A$ then $r_b(ab)=(ab)b'=a(bb')=ar_b(b')$.

Comment: Thanks. But it this way, if we want r to be a ring homomorphism, that is $r_{ab}=r_{a}r_{b}$, it seems we need to define $r_{a}r_{b}(b’)=b’ab$, but it seems strange.

Comment: It seems more reasonable to write $b’r_{b}=b’b$, then we have $b^{‘}r_{a}r_{b}=b^{‘}ab$, in this case, $r$ Is ring homomorphism, am I right?

Comment: You're right that $r$ is not a ring homomorphism--it reverses the order of multiplication.  It could be considered as a ring homomorphism $B^{op}\to E$ or $B\to E^{op}$ (the latter is what you are suggesting by writing $r_b$ on the right, which reverses the order of multiplication in $E$).

Comment: While I agree that the notation $r_b$ suggests that the author is considering $B$ as a left $A$-module here, I don't think that "left by default" is such standard practice as you suggest. It may be that "left" is still more common than "right", but my impression is that "right" has increased its market share over the years, although that may be biased by the kind of papers and books I read. [Full disclosure: I prefer "right".]